# ServiceWorker Notification Click - How can I refresh a page AND jump to an anchor link?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Basically, on my 'notificationclick' event, I am trying to open the notifications URL. It works perfectly for normal URLs. But if the URL has an anchor tag (#), it will then just try to jump to the specified anchor (which doesn't exist yet.)

I can easily cut out the anchor part of the url, and that works for the base page, it will then refresh the page successfully, but it wont jump to the comment.

So i tried doing this:

```
                if (cleanedClientUrl === cleanedUrl && 'focus' in client) {
                    //focus and reload the window that has this page open
                    client.focus();

                    //if the url had a # in it, first navigate to the cleaned url (otherwise it wont refresh)
                    if (url.indexOf('#'))
                        client.navigate(cleanedUrl);

                    client.navigate(url);

                    return;
                }
```

Which I was hoping would first redirect it to the URL without the cleanedUrl (without the anchor), and then navigate to the original url, which include the anchor, to make it jump down. But it seems the second client.navigate cancels the first one.

Is there any way to wait until the first one is loaded, or tell the page to reload even if there's an anchor specified in the URL?

Here is my full code:

```
//user clicked / tapped a push notification
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    const clickedNotification = event.notification;
    clickedNotification.close();

    //exit if the url could not be found
    if (!event.notification.data || !event.notification.data.url) return;

    //get url from event
    var url = event.notification.data.url;
    //if the url contains a #, remove it and everything after it
    var cleanedUrl = url.indexOf('#') ? url.substring(0, url.indexOf('#')) :url;

    event.waitUntil(
        self.clients.matchAll({type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true}).then( windowClients => {
            console.log('opening window', windowClients.length, 'windows')
            // Check if there is already a window/tab open with the target URL
            for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                var client = windowClients[i];

                //if the page url contains a #, remove it and everything after it
                var cleanedClientUrl;
                if (client.url.indexOf('#') !== -1)
                    cleanedClientUrl = client.url.substring(0, client.url.indexOf('#'));
                else cleanedClientUrl = client.url;

                // if the cleaned URLs match
                if (cleanedClientUrl === cleanedUrl && 'focus' in client) {
                    //focus and reload the window that has this page open
                    client.focus();

                    //if the url had a # in it, first navigate to the cleaned url (otherwise it wont refresh)
                    if (url.indexOf('#'))
                        client.navigate(cleanedUrl);

                    client.navigate(url);

                    return;
                }
            }
            // If not, then open the target URL in a new window/tab.
            if (self.clients.openWindow) {
                return self.clients.openWindow(url);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you quickly jump to the anchor and then immediately reload the page?

**main JS thread**

```
window.location = '#my-anchor-value';
window.location.reload();
```

**ServiceWorker**

if you need to chain navigation in a SW, you'll need to await the promise completion of the first `navigate()`

```
if (url.indexOf('#')) {
  return client.navigate(cleanedUrl)
  .then(() => client.navigate(url));
} else {
  return client.navigate(url);
}
```

Comment: The client doesn't seem to have access to reloading, or probably location. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowClient

Comment: correct, reloading must occur from main JS thread, not ServiceWorker

Comment: Yet you can 'navigate' which does the same thing as reload in all cases except mine. Although now I'm trying to just send a message to the page which then should reload itself, but even that isn't working with anchors.

Comment: consider using the `then()` of the first `navigate()` Promise

Comment: if your DOM anchor elements are not yet available during anchor navigation, consider `setTimeout()` to await DOM element or a more explicit callback to signal that the DOM is ready to be "anchored to"

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it seems you've pretty much figured it out, so thanks a ton. I think you have to add an argument to the then function, which passes a new client which it seems you have to use instead of the same client as before. And you were right about the anchor not being loaded yet. SetTimeout works, but I'm afraid it will fail on slower connections. Do you have any suggestions for the more explicit callback? Would I have to have the page signal the service worker once loaded, and have the service worker keep track of the pending second navigation somehow?

Comment: Generally, most of the single-page app frameworks fire events after components render, so perhaps you may be able to tie into that.  I generally recommend implementing redirection from the main app/JS thread and not SWs, but it seems a little complex to answer confidently.

Comment: Do you know of any way I could check if the client page is fully loaded from the `client` variable, or if there's a way I could trigger an event on it from the page?

Comment: I still don't see how it's going to work, because I cant send any data to the page other than navigating it, and it doesn't seem like the MessageEvent I would receive from postMessage has any identifying data, so I don't know how it would know it's the same page.

Comment: I didn't realize I could postMessage from the client, doing so and receiving that message on the page, then setting window.location.hash to the proper hash seems to work.